# C++ How does Qt work?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

I'm trying to figure out how to access components from Qt Designer form which I have inside my c++ project, there is no compile errors but runtime errors occur.

How does "main" function work and a.exec? Should I execute my code before a.exec() or create a new thread to do so?

```
QWidget *pWindow;
QPushButton *lpPushButton;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QtProject w;
   w.show();
   pWindow = QApplication::activeWindow();
   lpPushButton = pWindow->findChild<QPushButton*>("pushButton_2");;
   lpPushButton->setText("test");

   return a.exec();
}
```

Both pWindow and lpPushButton are NULL

The above code doesn't work since I have no idea where I can call setText from.
A little ELI5 explanation on how Qt works would be great, thank you.

Comment: what runtime errors do you get?

Comment: Access violations, but both lpPushButton and pWindow are NULL..

Comment: It's been years since I did any Qt work. Don't you register a handler for effectively "on application start"?

Comment: Qt is event driven, after you enter the event loop you need to react to events to do your work

Comment: Why would the window have a button?

Comment: Can you show the code of QtProject or even better: can you replace that with QMainWindow for a quick test?

Comment: What's wrong with simply doing the work in the constructor of `QtProject` class (which, presumably, has the button in question)? Or, at the very least, adding a method to `QtProject` that will set the button's text, and then calling that method like `w.setButtonText("test");`? It's a rather bad design to access internal GUI elements directly from outside the GUI class. The GUI class should encapsulate its internals, not expose them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a form using QtDesigner, it stores the details in a `xxx.ui` file which must be added to your project. This is compiled in a precompile step into a `ui_xxx.h` file which you must include in your source files.

This header file contains a generated class with all the widget and layout code inside and puts it in a namespace called `Ui`.

You have two options to use this generated class: you can derive from it, or you can have it as a member. You then need to call the class' `setupUi()` function to execute the creation/layout code.

The advantage of deriving from the generated class is that all child widgets are publicly available.

For example, if you create a simple widget form in QtDesigner and call it `MyWidget`, with a single `QPushButton` called `pushbutton_2`, you can create the form using the following code:

```
#include "ui_mywidget.h"
#include <qwidget.h>
#include <qapplication.h>

class Widget : public QWidget, public Ui::MyWidget{
public:
     Widget(QWidget *parent = 0):QWidget(parent){
         setupUi(this);
     }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    w.pushbutton_2->setText("test");

    return app.exec();
}
```

The reason you can access `pushbutton_2` directly is because it's a public member of `Ui::MyWidget` from which you derived `Widget`. It is also created when you call `setupUi()` from the constructor of `Widget`.

EDIT:
Another way of creating a form is to have your generated class a member class in your display widget. You will still need to call `setupUi()` though, in order to create all the form's child widgets and perform layout tasks.

```
class Widget : public QWidget{
public:
     Widget(QWidget *parent = 0):QWidget(parent){
         ui.setupUi(this);
     }

private:
    Ui::MyWidget ui;
};
```

In this case, you will not be able to access the child widgets directly. The reason is that, although structurely, they might be children of `Widget`, the pointer variables that hold the memory addresses to them, and were used to create them, belong to `ui`, which is a private member of `Widget`.

You can still access them, however, using the `findChild<>()` function, if you know their object names.

Comment: I tried but I can't access any child element with `w.pushButton_2`

But i can do this 
`QPushButton *lpTestBtn  = w.parent()->findChild<QPushButton*>("TestBtn");`

Comment: I've added a second way of using the QtDesigner-generated classes. Perhaps this is the way you were implementing them.